# Grails unit test failing in Grails 2.x

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy

We have a class that uses Groovy's invokeMethod interceptor to intercept all static method calls on a class. It's used to define rules pulled from the database. Recently, we upgraded to Grails 2.3.4 from 1.3.7 and the unit test testing this class is now failing if I invoke a method that has already been defined. It works fine if the method has not been defined. Here's a much simplified version of what we're doing.

```
class TestUtil {
static {

    TestUtil.metaClass.'static'.invokeMethod = { String m_name, args ->

        def method = TestUtil.metaClass.getMetaMethod(m_name, args)
        if(!method) {
            //define it
            TestUtil.metaClass.'static'."${m_name}" = { argz ->
                return argz[0]
            }
        }

        //call it
        "${m_name}"(args)
        }
    }
}

class TestUtilTest extends GrailsUnitTestCase {
void testMethodNotExist() {
    def result = TestUtil.testMethod("not exist")

    assertEquals result, "not exist"
}

void testExistingMethod() {
    def result = TestUtil.testMethod("exist")

    assertEquals result, "exist"
}
}
```

The error I get is: |  groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static TestUtil.testMethod() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [exist]

When used in the context of the application, the code works fine...it's just the unit test that's breaking and I can't quite figure out why.

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem or not but shouldn't you be calling `TestUtil.metaClass.getStaticMetaMethod` instead of just `getMetaMethod`?

Answer (score 1):

Wow, from 1.3.7 to 2.3.4..... A giant leap for mankind. :)

You are getting the error because of extending `GrailsUnitTestCase`.

If you are not doing any kind of mocking in the test for the util class then you can modify the test class to extend `GroovyTestCase` instead of `GrailsUnitTestCase`. It should work.

`GrailsUnitTestCase` is not encouraged to use in newer version of Grails. With Grails 2.3.4 you get spock by default when you create tests from command line or create any artefact, and you should not see any problem either if you use spock test as below:

```
import spock.lang.Specification

class TestUtilSpec extends Specification {

    void "test both in one test case"(){
        expect:
            result == TestUtil.testMethod(arg)

        where:
            arg         || result
            "not exist" || "not exist"
            "exist"     || "exist"
    }
}
```

Comment: Grails 2.3.4 tests use JUnit by default. They only use Spock if you extend `Specification` as in your example

Comment: Grails 2.3.4 creates spock `Specification` in particular when you "create" tests using create-unit-test/create-integration-test or any other artefact is what I meant. :) @Don

Comment: You're right it does. I didn't know that, because I never use those commands. Nevertheless I doubt OP wants to migrate his tests from JUnit to Spock just to fix this, but I agree that he should stop extending `GrailsUnitTestCase`

Comment: I did try not extending GrailsUnitTestCase, but I'm still running into the same issue. Something must be going on with the environment when running the test, because it definitely works fine when I run the app itself and use this same code.

Comment: @user1895955 Dis you inherit GroovyTestCase instead?

Comment: @Don AFAIT using commands to create tests is the best practice. I have seen weird issues with only creating groovy classes and trying to test it. Moreover, using commands helps in not bothering about the nomenclature of the test case, for example, name changed from `*Test` to `*Tests` from Grails 2.0 >

Comment: @dmahapatro the commands don't do anything other than creating the test class. I always create the class myself and have never run into any problems. The fact that the commands now default to Spock is another reason for me not to use them, because my tests use JUnit

Comment: I'm still running into the same issues, even when just extending GroovyTestCase. I'll try to generate a brand new test case using the Spock Specification and see if I can get it to work somehow.

Comment: @user1895955 you could also try extending nothing and annotate the class with `@TestMixin(GrailsUnitTestMixin)` instead

Comment: The only way that I was able to make it work is if I combined all of the unit tests into one unit test method. As soon as I break them out into multiple tests(methods), it breaks. Not sure what is happening between each test being called that is breaking the meta programming stuff, but that's kind of strange.

Comment: @user1895955 If viable, write/mimic to new test (or spock spec) for the same and discard the old one.